# Pytorch LSTM and cross entropy

Tags: python, numpy, nlp, pytorch, cross-entropy

I am working on sentiment analysis, I want to classify the output into 4 classes. For **loss** I am using **cross-entropy**.

The problem is PyTorch cross-entropy needs the input of **(batch_size, output)** which is am having trouble with.

I am taking a **batch size of 12** and **sequence size is 32**

```
import torch.nn as nn


class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_dim = 256, input_size = 32 , num_layers = 1, num_classes=4, vocab_size = len(vocab_to_int)+1, embedding_dim=100):
        super().__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embedding_dim, hidden_dim, num_layers)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, 50)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(50, 4)

    
    def forward(self, x, hidden):
        x = self.embedding(x)
        x = x.view(32, 12, 100)
        x, hidden = self.lstm(x, hidden)
        x = x.contiguous().view(-1, 256)
        x = self.fc1(x) # output shape ([384, 50])
        x = self.fc2(x) # output shape [384, 4]
        return x, hidden
    
    def init_hidden(self, batch_size=12):
        weight = next(self.parameters()).data
        hidden = (weight.new(self.num_layers, 12, self.hidden_dim).zero_().cuda(), weight.new(self.num_layers, 12, self.hidden_dim).zero_().cuda())
        return hidden
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "am having trouble with.". (see [mcve]).

Comment: The thing is, after the linear layer the output size is (384, 4) which is (batch_size*sequence_size, num of classes = 4).
But Cross entropy expects ( batch_size, num_classes). 

error from cross entropy:


ValueError: Expected input batch_size (384) to match target batch_size (12).

Comment: the output of your forward function has to be 12 x 4 x 1. 12 at the beginning because it is your batch size. But the batch size seems to get lost in your forward function because of some reshapes you did

Answer (score 1):

According to [the CrossEntropyLoss docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html):

> input has to be a Tensor of size `(C)` for unbatched input, `(minibatch,C)` [for batched input] [...]

The code you provided is only the RNN class and not the data processing and the actual call to `CrossEntropyLoss`, but the error you stated in the comments makes me think that you didn't **reshape the labels tensor** to have the same size as the output from the neural network. Therefore, you'd be calculating the loss of a tensor with size `(384, 4)` against another tensor which I infer is of size `(12, 32)`. Your labels tensor should be of size `(384)` to match the first dimension of the neural network output.

Also, you don't have to manually reshape your tensors, you can reshape them after the `forward()` call through the `torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence()` function. If you do apply this function to both the output of the neural network and the labels, you will have a tensor of size `(384, 4)` that PyTorch can handle in the call to `CrossEntropyLoss`. See the note in [the `pack_padded_sequence()` function docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence.html) for more details.